# javascript regular expression to replace Math.cos trouble

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace some `math` functions with `Math.sin`. This is what I've tried. I expect the results to be that `Math.cos` would be replaced by `Math.sin`

```
  re=/[Math\.cos|Math\.tan]/g;
  s="Math.cos(0)+Math.cos(0)";
  s=s.replace(re,"Math.sin");
  alert(s);
```

The result I would expect would be `Math.sin(0)+Math.sin(0)` instead it is

```
Math.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sin(0)+Math.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sinMath.sin(0)
```

I'm not sure what to try to fix the code.

Comment: Why on earth would this be something you need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The square brackets radically change the meaning of your regular expression. Get rid of them.

```
re = /Math\.cos|Math\.tan/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have square brackets (meaning match any of the characters between the brackets) rather than parenthesis (meaning group these different expressions/return as a match), try:

```
 re=/(Math\.cos|Math\.tan)/g;
```